# using pattern in variable in preg_match php returns false

Tags: php, string, preg-match

I want check if a string contains a variable amount of generated words. This is the code I came up with, it stores the pattern in a variable which I put in the preg_match.

**Result of this code:** it returns true;

```
$string = "What a beatiful world";

$pieces = "#\b(" . implode("|",$pieces_arr). ")\b#";
```

`$pieces` outputs for example:

```
#\b(hello|you)\b#
```

into:

```
if(preg_match($pieces, $string)) {  

        echo "piece found in string!!";

}
```

Comment: remove the single quotes.

Comment: And in situations like this, `preg_quote()` is usually advisable

Comment: After removing the single quotes every result is true. I will take a look at `preg_quote()`.  Updated the post.